# Bitwise Shifts steps

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have some questions on bitwise operations, any help will be appreciated.

1.)

```
i = 0x000a;
printf( "2: %x %x %x\n", i, i << 1, i << 2 );
i = 0x0010;
printf( "3: %x %x %x\n", i, i >> 1, i >> 2 );
```

2)

```
unsigned int i = 1;
printf( "1: %x %x %x\n", i, ~i, ~~i );
printf( "2: %x %x \n", i, ( 0x0100 & ( 1 << 8 ) ) >> 8 );
printf( "3: %x %x \n", i, 0x0100 ^ ( 1 << 8 ) );
printf( "4: %x %x \n", i, 0x0100 | ( 1 << 4 ) );
```

I have answers to these questions, but do not understand how it works. Can Anyone explain them in steps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Diego Basch, what is printed?

Comment: Did you try compiling it and seeing what it prints?

Comment: Im saying that, I have answers to them. but I dont understand.the output for this printf( "2: %x %x %x\n", i, i << 1, i << 2 );  is 2: a 14 28. However, I cant simply get those numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x<<SOME_VALUE` moves all the bits of x SOME_VALUE times to the left. Thus `0x000a=1010(2)`, when shifted 1 bit to the left will become `10100` or `0x0014`. Shifting this number once more to the left will multiply it by two or produce 0x0028. The logic for right shift(>>) is similar and I will not explain it here. I think this explains what you ask for in your comment.

`~` negates all bits of an integer and thus all the 0 bits become 1s and vice versa. So `~0x0001(1(2))` is `fffffffe` or `11111111111111111111111111111110(2)`(on a 32 bit computer). Double negation produces the input.

`&` is bitwise "and" operator and is a binary operator - it takes two operands and the resulting number will have a 1 at a given position if and only if both numbers have 1 at that position.

`^` or xor is an exclusive or operator and again is binary. Here you will have 1 if and only if **exactly one** of the operands has 1 at the given position.

And lastly '|' is logical or, again binary operator and has a 1 at a given position if and only if **at least one** of its operands has 1 at this position.

Answer (score 1):

simplest explanation i can give to your query is,

when you apply right shift operator by n bit, result will be /(2^n), and
when you apply left shift operator by n bit, result will be *(2^n).

For example,

(10 << 1) will give result 20 and (10 >> 1) will give result 5